# Getting error while running the query

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code.

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\speednet\speed_net.accdb")
Dim com As New OleDbCommand
con.Open()
com.Connection = con
com.CommandText = "insert into users (name,username,password,user_type) values ('" & name1.Text & "' ,'" & username.Text & "' ,'" & password.Text & "','" & account_type.Text & "')"
com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error:

> Syntax error in insert into statement ...

Cant find out the problem.

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: Password is a reserved keyword in access. Use it with square brackets `[password]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Password is a reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in access. You need square brackets around that word.
But your query should also be modified to use a [parameter approach](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of string concatenation, otherwise more dangerous situation will be possible. Read about [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and what happen if one of your concatenated string contains a single quote.

So

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection("....")
Using com = New OleDbCommand("insert into users " & _ 
                             "(name,username,[password],user_type) " & _ 
                             "values (@name, @uname,@pass,@acctype)", con)
    con.Open()
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name1.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctype", account_type.Text)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```